# inverse trig and an algebra nitpick?

Tags: calculus

Let's say you have:

$-cot(y)=FOO$.
Normally, you would multiply through by (-1)

$cot(y)=-FOO$

and finally,

$y=cot^{-1}(-FOO)$

But, is it valid to go from

$-cot(y)=FOO$

to

$y=-cot^{-1}(FOO)$ ?

Does this only work in certain situations?
Even/Odd function?

(By the way, how can I format this better?  Each equation on a new line, without skipping lines)

Comment: You can add newline equations using double dollar signs: `$$ \ldots $$` results in: $$ \ldots $$
Likewise, you can use `\begin{align*} y &= 2x \\ z &= 2y \end{align*}` to align equations within a grouping: $$\begin{align*} y &= 2x, \\ z &= 2y. \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $-f(x) \neq f(-x)$.

However, since $\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x} = \frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, it happens that $$\cot -x = \frac{\sin -x}{\cos -x} = \frac{-\sin x}{\cos x} = -\cot x.$$

Functions that share the property $-f(x) = f(-x)$ are called 'odd functions'. Functions such that $f(x) = f(-x)$ are called 'even functions'. Products of even and odd functions are much like products of even and odd numbers. $\sin x$ is odd, $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ is even; hence the product of the two is odd.